# Is there is a way to make a spring boot app to be able to see a config folder in Resources and get its config whenever it needs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, resources

I have a **config folder** of **xml** files that my spring boot app needs , its located on the same level of **src** folder ... Now i now to locate it in **Resources Folder** on the same level of **application.properties**.. There is any way to be able to do that ?

Comment: Web search: [Spring Boot External Configuration](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=Spring+Boot+External+Configuration). Question down-voted because it "does not show any **research** effort" *(quoted tooltip of down-vote button)*

Comment: i did alot researches .. but what i need is diff .. i have a config folder of xml files related to jpos framework to work with financial transactions..  its not sth like jpos.isoChannel.port=5000 and then extract it from a config class.. NO, its a xml config file related to JPOS that it needs to start.. now its in the same level with src folder level and now i want to put it in resources folder and still be able to see it the same way as it was before..

Comment: Any file put in the `src/resources` folder will be on the classpath at runtime, same as the `application.properties` file. That is standard Maven project setup and has nothing to do with Spring Boot. If you're reading resources with Spring, use the [`ClassPathResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) class.

Comment: Bro how can i contact you cuz my problem is a lil complicated than that

Comment: Then how about you edit the question and clarify what issue you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There many way to read your file .properties:

You can read with plain java like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
```

you can use the `@PropertySource` annotation in a Spring `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("db.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    // more config ...
}
//Or if you your config outside of your classpath, you can use the file: prefix:
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/application.properties")
```

Using Multiple file :

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:bar.properties")
})
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

And so on ...